# Recursive CTE to use a defined function to display total number of successes and fails for the function

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a user defined function which takes a message (VARCHAR) as a parameter and returns a 1 if message contains a defined substring and a 0 if it does not. This code works as intended:

```
--Create function to take one VARCHAR parameter and return one INTEGER
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.checkLetters (@MESSAGE VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS INTEGER
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
    --Variable to store the 1 or 0
    DECLARE @value INTEGER;

    --Match
    IF @MESSAGE LIKE '%lhl%'
        SET @value = 1

    --No Match
    ELSE
        SET @value = 0

    RETURN @value
END;
```

I now want to create a recursive CTE that applies this function to a particular column in a table which contains a large string. However I want this CTE display the total number of 1's, and the total number of 0's returned from the entire table. How would I go about doing this?

This is how I would think to do it:

1. Read first row and perform function on message column
2. Increment variable 1 (success) or 0 (fail
3. Repeat over rest of rows and increment again
4. Return table of total1's and total0's

I do not want to use a cursor.

Comment: You do not want a recursive CTE either...

Comment: rCTE is a bad fit for this problem because you do not have a logical link from one object to the next.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to count the number of rows from a table that matches `'%lhl%'`, or whatever string pattern. You can do this using a simple `SELECT` statement:

```
DECLARE @pattern VARCHAR(10) = '%lhl%'

SELECT
    Successes   = SUM(CASE WHEN [message] LIKE @pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Fails       = SUM(CASE WHEN [message] LIKE @pattern THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)      
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Cheers for that! but I am trying to practice CTE recursion if you have any help on that front.

Comment: This is not the appropriate problem to practice recursive CTE on.

Comment: Just because it can be done an easier way doesn't mean its not worth practicing on.

Comment: If you want to practice on rCTE, you should try solving hierarchy-type problems or problems with parent-children type relation ship.